Why does changing the order of composition of a bijective function and its inverse change the identity map?
I am watching a series of videos which serve as an introduction to naive set theory.
I was told the following in the video:

For a bijective function $f$:
$$f:A\rightarrow B
\\f\circ f^{-1}=id_{B}
\\f^{-1}\circ f=id_{A}$$

It makes sense to me that $f^{-1}\circ f=id_{A}$ because in my head I can just imagine $f^{-1}(f(x))$, which would just return $x$. The thing I can't understand is how changing the order of composition would give $id_{B}$, and why it wouldn't give $id_{A}$ (in my mind I can visualize the two functions cancelling out and thus we would be left with our original input set, $A$). How does the order affect whether it's $id_{a}$ or $id_{b}$?

Have you written out any examples?  $f: {1,2} \to {a,b}$ by $f(1)=a$, $f(2)=b$.

Think what are the domain and range of $f\circ f^{-1}$. In order to equal to $id_A$ this has to be map from $A$ to $A$. Is that the case?

The function $f^{-1}$ is a function from $B$ to $A$ and not the other way around, if that helps. Try drawing blobs for the sets $A,B$ and arrows between them for the functions.

Another way to help you would be to set $g:=f^{-1}$, so that $g^{-1}=f$. Then $g:B\to A$, and $g^{-1}\circ g=\text{id}_B$ (that already make sense to you). And this statement is equivalent to $f\circ f^{-1}=\text{id}_B$!

Thanks for your help guys! The blob analogy and setting $g$ worked really the best for me, but I am wondering if there is a more concrete proof for this (other than common sense). I thought about using examples but that doesn’t look concrete enough and I am still a bit confused as to how I would find the range and composition of this.

If you want to do it more formally,  you have to look more closely into what the notations $f:A\to B$, $f^{-1}$, and $\circ$ actually mean. You can't do rigorous proofs without concrete and rigorous definitions to work with.
